# C# Composite Control will lose name at design and run time

Tags: c#, winforms, composite-controls

I developed a composite control using C# Windows Forms Control Library and code as follow:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler NameChanged;
    protected virtual void OnNameChanged()
    {
        EventHandler handler = NameChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void WhenNameChanged(object sender , EventArgs e)
    {
        this.myGroupBox.Text = this.Name;
    }

    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();

        IComponentChangeService changeService = (IComponentChangeService)GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService));
        if (changeService == null) return; // not provided at runtime, only design mode

        changeService.ComponentChanged -= OnComponentChanged; // to avoid multiple subscriptions
        changeService.ComponentChanged += OnComponentChanged;
    }

    private void OnComponentChanged(object sender, ComponentChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Component == this && e.Member.Name == "Name")
        {
            OnNameChanged();
        }
    }

    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.NameChanged += new EventHandler(this.WhenNameChanged);
    }
}
```

The `MyControl` only has one `GroupBox` control named `myGroupBox`

```
private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox myGroupBox;
```

I have a test program which is a C# Windows Forms Application, and I would like to see that when I change the name of `myGroupBox` in properties window, the text of `myGroupBox` will be the name I typed. so I typed a name `Value` to `myGroupBox` in the properties window, the text will change in designer, here is the screenshot:
[image]

But when I rebuild the test program or at run time the text of `myGroupBox` will disappear, here is the screenshot:

[image]

what should I do with my code? thanks

Comment: Can you try to debug this? (like a messagebox in `WhenNameChanged`). When you set the `Name` of `myGroupBox` you are setting a property of a `GroupBox`, not of a `MyControl`, so `WhenNameChanged` is not part here. `GroupBox` sets it's `Text` to it's `Name` when no other `Text` was specified. So it would be interesting when exactly that `Text` is reset.

Comment: I debugged, and found out that It's the constructor `MyControl` to reset the `Text` to an empty string, at the construction time, the `Name` is empty

Comment: I have no idea how to solve this

Comment: update my previous answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that the `Name` of a `Control` (or `UserControl`) is empty after construction. The name given by you and stored in the resources will be set in `OnLoad`.
So a solution for you could be to override `OnLoad` with something like this:

```
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
    // ... the code so far

    // override OnLoad
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        myGroupBox.Text = Name; // or WhenNameChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

So the name taken from the resources (e.g. after rebuild/reopen designer) will be set here again and so also set as `myGroupBox.Text`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried, but failed, I call `WhenNameChanged` like this:`WhenNameChanged(this , EventArgs.Empty);`

Comment: Yes, I called it like you did

Comment: I tried just now, it works fine, thank you very much again!

Comment: I have another problem, I create a new user control inherited from `MyControl` named `DerivedControl`, and in the test program in the design mode the text of `GroupBox` showed a wrong text, but when the test program running, the text of `GroupBox` showed correctly, why?

Comment: @TwenteMaster Sorry, can't tell you from that short description. We will not solve this in the comments...maybe open a new question?